# Notation -- How do I denote the derivative of a reciprocal evaluated at some value?

Tags: derivatives, notation

Let's say I have a function $f(x)$. To denote the reciprocal, I denote it as $f(x)^{-1}$. If I want to take the derivative of that, I think it's written as $(f(x)^{-1})'$. Then if I want to have that function evaluated as some number say $0$, how would I write it?

Comment: How about $(f^{-1})^\prime(0)$?

Comment: @MichaelBiro I was thinking of that but I was worried I'd be denoting inverse instead of reciprocal

Comment: OK, so instead do $(\frac{1}{f})^\prime(0)$?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey That should work well. Thanks!

Comment: You could also simply write $-f'(0)/f(0)^2$....